# Facing issue in making a patch for a bug on bugzilla

Tags: mozilla, bugzilla

I am trying to make a patch for a bug on bugzilla but I am facing an issue of "the number of limits reached" in watchman.Despite setting the limits on the number of watches, I am not able to make the patch.Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean or what's the problem. Would you mind adding details to your question? What commands did you try? What's the output of the failing command? Otherwise it's unlikely that we'd be able to help.

Comment: I am facing an issue with watchman saying:inotify limits reached.I had reset the limits,but still getting the same error.

Comment: You should probably just disable watchman from your mercurial configuration (.hgrc).

Comment: I am trying to submit the patch through mercurial mq.How can I enable the extension?